# How to move certain commit to NEW branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I have commit X and 2 commits after it. I should move only X to new branch. How can I do this?
(And my repo is in remote repo also, I don't think exactly what is it, but I won't get "detached head")
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If commit X is the only commit you want to port to the new branch and the branch is new, simply start the new branch from that commit.

```
$ git branch newbranch COMMIT_HASH
```

If you want to move commit X to an existing branch and commit X doesn't necessary fit the branch history, then you can [cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the commit

```
$ git cherry-pick COMMIT_HASH
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. 
If I'll use "git branch newbranch COMMIT_HASH" will the commit be deleted from current branch (master for me)?

Comment: @Metalex No it will not be automatically deleted, it'll just create a new branch starting at that commit.  To remove it you'll have to use the `rebase` or `revert` command.